# how to prevent window from closing on ESC extjs 4

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am stuck with one problem with one problem in stop the window from closing using ESC button.

The window gets closed as soon as I click the ESC button from my keyboard. I want the window should not close, **instead it should prompt a message box asking 'YOU REALLY WANTS TO close' with two button yes or cancel**

If person click yes button the the window should destroy and else the window should be as it is.

but don't know why the window is getting close on ESC press.

I am prompting message as the user click the esc button using below code

```
listeners: {
        show : function(win) {
          Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyNav', win.getEl(), {
            "esc" : function(e){
              alert('hi.. closing');
              win.hide();
            },
            scope: win
          });
        }
      }
```

now I want the message box to be appeared and based on the person answer things to be happend.
any help ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is very convenient [onEsc](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-onEsc) function in `window`'s config. Use it this way:

```js
onEsc: function() {
    var me = this;
    Ext.Msg.confirm(
        'Closing confirmation',
        'YOU REALLY WANTS TO close',
        function(btn) {
            if (btn === 'yes')
                me.hide();
        }
     );
},
```

Here is [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/v7WKh/1/).

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [beforeclose](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-event-beforeclose) event.